# acceder a tipo de objeto en botón wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de WPF un formulario de gestión de empleados y no consigo dar con la manera de acceder al tipo de objeto "Empleado", que es la clase padre, de un array de empleados para encontrar los métodos de las clases hijas(EmpleadoFijo, EmpleadoTemporal y EmpleadoxHoras) en el botón `private void btCalcularSueldo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`, cada clase hija tiene un método específico para calcular su sueldo,  necesito por favor alguna guía para poder continuar. Pego en el código de la clase que controla el método del botón del formulario donde estoy atascado.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace EjercicioWPF1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        List<Empleado> lista_empleados = new List<Empleado>();
        int posicion = 0;
        

       public MainWindow()
        {
            Empleado emp1 = new EmpleadoFijo("Juan", 31, "34876273f", "técnico", 1000, 2017);
            Empleado emp2 = new EmpleadoTemporal("Lucas", 38, "45632187d", "administración", 1100, new DateTime(2011, 6, 3), new DateTime(2012, 6, 3));
            Empleado emp3 = new EmpleadoxHoras("Sandra", 28, "29463218t", "ventas", 900, 90);
            lista_empleados.Add(emp1);
            lista_empleados.Add(emp2);
            lista_empleados.Add(emp3);
            this.DataContext = lista_empleados; 
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btCalcularSueldo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


    EmpleadoFijo empp1 = new EmpleadoFijo();
    EmpleadoTemporal empp2 = new EmpleadoTemporal();
    EmpleadoxHoras empp3 = new EmpleadoxHoras();
    for (int i = 0; i < lista_empleados.Count-1; i++)
    {
        if (empp1.GetType() == lista_empleados[i].GetType())

        {
            empp1 = (EmpleadoFijo)lista_empleados[i];
            Calcularsueldo.Text = empp1.sueldo_fijo().ToString();
        }
        if(empp2.GetType() == lista_empleados[i].GetType())
        {
            empp2 = (EmpleadoTemporal)lista_empleados[i];
            Calcularsueldo.Text = empp2.sueldo_temporal().ToString();
        }
        if(empp3.GetType() == lista_empleados[i].GetType())
        {
            empp3 = (EmpleadoxHoras)lista_empleados[i];
            Calcularsueldo.Text = empp3.sueldo_total_e_horas().ToString();
        }
    }

        }
        private void btNuevo_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            VentanaIntermedia ventana = new VentanaIntermedia();
            ventana.ShowDialog();
        }
        private void btsiguiente_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            posicion++;

            int tope = lista_empleados.Count;
            tope = tope - 1;
            if (posicion > tope)
            {
                posicion = 0;
            }
            if (posicion == 0)
            {
                Nombre.Text = lista_empleados[0].Nombre;
                Edad.Text = lista_empleados[0].Edad.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= tope; i++)
                {
                    if (i == posicion)
                    {
                        Nombre.Text = lista_empleados[i].Nombre;
                        Edad.Text = lista_empleados[i].Edad.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        private void btanterior_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            posicion--;
            if (posicion < 0)
            {
                posicion = lista_empleados.Count-1;
            }

            int minimo = 0;
           

            if (posicion == 0)
            {
                Nombre.Text = lista_empleados[0].Nombre;
                Edad.Text = lista_empleados[0].Edad.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = lista_empleados.Count-1; i > minimo; i--)
                {

                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        i = lista_empleados.Count;
                    }

                    if (i == posicion)
                    {
                        Nombre.Text = lista_empleados[i].Nombre;
                        Edad.Text = lista_empleados[i].Edad.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Por ejemplo aquí pongo la clase EmpleadoFijo para que se vea el método al que pretendo llamar: `public double sueldo_fijo()` desde MainWindow

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EjercicioWPF1
{
    internal class EmpleadoFijo : Empleado
    {
        #region atributo
        private int anio_alta;
        private double sueldo_E_fijo;
        #endregion
        #region propiedades


        public double Sueldo_E_fijo
        {
            get { return sueldo_E_fijo; }
            set { }
        }
        public int Anio_alta
        {
            get { return anio_alta; }
            set { anio_alta = value; }
        }
        #endregion
        #region constructor
        public EmpleadoFijo(string nombre, int edad, string nif, string puesto,int sueldo_base, int anio_alta)
            : base(nombre, edad, nif, puesto, sueldo_base)
        {
            this.Anio_alta = anio_alta;
            Sueldo_E_fijo = sueldo_fijo();
        }
        #endregion

        public double sueldo_fijo()
        {
            string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
            int antiguedad = int.Parse(date) - Anio_alta;
            int extra = antiguedad*50;
            sueldo_E_fijo = Sueldo_base + extra;
            return sueldo_E_fijo;
        }
        #region override tostring
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString() + " año de alta: " + Anio_alta; 
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Con `lista_empleados[i] = empp;` estás reemplazando los elementos de la lista con una misma instancia vacia de empleado. No me parece que realmente quieras hacer eso. Explicate mejor porque no comprendo qué funciones no encuentras, ni a qué te refieres por clases hijas ya que solo veo que estás usando la clase `List` y `Empleado`

Comment: He editado la pregunta... Lo que ocurre es que los objetos son por ejemplo EmpleadoFijo que hereda de Empleado, y quiero acceder a EmpleadoFijo que tiene su método de calcular sueldo y asociarlo al método private void btCalcularSueldo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

Comment: No entiendo tu problema... Es objeto.Metodo para acceder a cualquier metodo... con lo cual no termino de entender tu problema...

Comment: El problema es que en el formulario de MainWindow se muestra con binding 1 Empleado, puede ser de tipo EmpleadoFijo, EmpleadoTemporal o EmpleadoxHoras, entonces en el botón para calcular el sueldo primero tengo que saber que tipo de empleado es ya que el método para calcular el sueldo es distinto para cada tipo de empleado e está implementado en su clase correspondiente

Comment: Por lo que pides parece todavía no comprendes como funciona la herencia y el polimorfismo. ¿Es así?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para reconocer tipos de objeto personalizados puedes probar con `typeof`, con esto puedes hacer un `switch` o un `if` múltiple y declararlo así:

```
EmpleadoFijo e;
if(e.GetType() == typeOf(EmpleadoFijo))
{
 //es un EmpleadoFijo
}
```

Creo que no necesito mostrar la solución más a detalle porque realmente es muy sencillo.